why my button isn't showing clicked in unity
So i was following this tutorial https://youtu.be/lF26yGJbsQk to make a start button for my unity game. But some how the button is not working and don't know why?




I don't see an Event System object in your scene. Did you accidentally delete it? See this past Q&A about a similar issue. Remember that code should always be shared as text, never as an image — visit the [help] if you need support formatting your code correctly.

Thank you so much, by mistakely i had deleted the Event System object.
